# Delphi Datasnap : How to send raw data to web REST client in delphi 10.3.2?

Tags: delphi, datasnap

When I used Delphi XE8, I use the following code to send text or image to a browser, without JSON values.
This code doesn't work anymore :

Server code :

```
function TTest.GetText: TStream
begin
  result := TStringStream.create('test');
end
```

For this example, the URL is http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/TTest/GetText

With XE8, the result is  :

```
test
```

With 10.3.2, the result is :

```
{"result":[[116,101,115,116]]}
```

How to disable JSON result formatting ?

Thank you for your help !

JP

Comment: Sorry It was with 10.3.2...
Now 10.3.3 is available, I'll test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parameter `json=false`:

```
http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/TTest/GetText?json=false
```

font:

```
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/DBX_Parameter_Caching
```